Why does this React Native Javascript function always delete the whole folder
What Software am I using?
from Package.json:
{
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-file-system": "~16.0.9",
    "expo-permissions": "^14.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6
}

What i want to do?
I want to delete a File using the expo-file-system package as my way to manipulate the File System of my Samsung Phone.
How i am actually doing it?
I am using this Code:

import * as EFS from "expo-file-system";

class ExternalFileSystemAdapterClient {
  constructor () {}

  public async deleteFile({ SAFPath, fileName }) {
    const pathToFile = SAFPath + fileName;
    logger.log(logName + " Deleting File: " + (pathToFile))
    await EFS.StorageAccessFramework.deleteAsync(pathToFile)
      .then(logger.log(logName + " File successfully deleted!"))
      .catch((e) => logger.error(logName + e));


  }
}

I call it with this:

import ExternalFileSystemAdapterClient from "./components/functions/file-system/external-file-system";

const efs = new ExternalFileSystemAdapterClient ()
  // Delete File
  try {
    logger.log(
      await efs.deleteFile({
        SAFPath: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATest/",
        fileName: "Peter.txt",
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    logger.warn(logName + error);
  }

Console Output:
"PermissionState": {"directoryUri": "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATest", "granted": true}
ExternalFileSystemAdapter:  Deleting File: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATest/Peter.txt
ExternalFileSystemAdapter:  File successfully deleted!

Whats the Problem?
Actually the Problem is that not the File gets deleted, as i would expect, but its deleting the Folder recursively - while the API Documentation says that there will be the file deleted, if provided...
maybe i messed something up?
